# What's the benefit of using local Service in Android

Tags: android

After a few years of hiatus I am brushing up my knowledge of Android by doing a side project. I found I don't see the point of using local Service in Android, such as the example given here: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Service, especially the local one, has the overhead of boiler plate code of Binder, bindServer(), ServiceConnection(...), but you didn't get anything you couldn't achieve with some vanilla local java code. The Service is independent and orthogonal to the async process and extra threads.

If all you do is have a local Service and do synchronous calls on it, what's the main benefit of using Service?

Answer (score 0):

Basically a Service can be used to perform a task that is long running like a music player or downloading. It doesn't specifically has a UI so if you are trying to do something in your activity and you do not want to make the user wait for something while blocking the activity than you should use Service for that becuase service has no UI and it will do its task in the background.

To sum up, you should use a service for critical operations like uploading photo, and you can use multi-threading where interrupting the operation is not critical.

Comment: For long running tasks such as uploading photo, the critical thing to do is to run it in a separate thread instead of the main UI thread. My understanding is that's independent of whether it done in Service or just a plain AsyncTask. Whether or not you use Service or not, offloading it to a separate thread is a must. The question is what's the benefit of adding extra layer of code to do it in a Service. Also, how about Local service code that doesn't not require additional thread as shown in the developer.android.com sample?

Comment: No AsyncTask will not work on something that requires time. Asynctask do give us the favor that it runs on background thread but if you continue something too long on it, It will be destroyed automatically. Where as Service will last longer.

Comment: And if you actually want your service not to consume UI Thread then you can make an Intent Service that executes on its on worker thread ( Background Thread ).

Comment: Yes, I agree with you on AsyncTask and IntentService. However, my question remains: what's the benefit of using Service if you don't need multithreading? The example given at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample seems a whole lot of boiler plate for something you can easily accomplish with straightforward vanilla code. I hope I didn't confuse you. And I really appreciate you looking into my question.

Comment: I don't think you would use service if you don't need multi-threading.

Comment: Yes that is true but it depends on the situation. Like what if you want to make an alarm that will ring on a specified time, Of course it is only possible if you are using service for that reason using a asynctask is not advised.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I feel too. And, for things like schedule an alarm, instead of using Service, the JobScheduler will be better: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, I did some more digging and I believe the main benefit of using Service is it introduces an alternative scope: life cycle.

If you want to do some asynchronous processing when the user navigates away from your UI, then only by using Service, you give the android system a signal not to kill the async background processing.

In short, using Service for synchronous processing makes little sense. But you better put async processing inside a Service if your app is going to be in the background when the async processing is going on.

In a sense, AsyncTask and explicit thread management is for foreground async processing to avoid the ANR of the main UI thread. Service is Android's solution for background processing. The subtle difference is between 'background' and 'async'

I guess in the official Android doc, by "background", they really mean without an UI/Activity, but often, people interpret it as non-UI thread.

Here are a few links that I found explains the problem well:
http://cogitolearning.co.uk/2013/06/android-service-vs-background-threads/
[When to use and when not to use a Service in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148724/when-to-use-and-when-not-to-use-a-service-in-android)